# How to rename a file using the Github API?

Tags: github, github-api

Is there a way to rename files using the Github API?
Currently I'm getting the file contents using `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path`, creating a new file with that content and the desired name and then deleting the original file which can end up quite heavy on the server with large files. Surely there's a better way!

Comment: There's no documented way of doing it

Comment: @sigmavirus24 Strictly speaking your statement is incorrect, as all of the building blocks are there, you just need to know how to put them together. From a practical viewpoint, however, you are correct :-(

Answer (score 1):

The only *other* way that I am aware of, beside your current get/create/delete, is to follow the steps outlined in [this blog post](http://www.levibotelho.com/development/commit-a-file-with-the-github-api/) by [Levi Botelho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1068266/levi-botelho):

1. Get the repository tree
2. Modify the references in that tree
3. Create a commit which references the modified tree
4. Move the HEAD reference to the new commit

This will cause more requests than your current solution but *might* send less data over the wire, *if* the contents in the file you are renaming is less than twice the size of the data that describes the tree...

Comment: Sorry about the late reply but I'll give it a go in the next few days and mark as accepted if it works. Thanks a lot!